# Pymongo query on a cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a large collection (73 million entries) that I want to do operations on. First I want to query away ~98% of the data, and then do larger operations on the last 2%. First I do

```
query_cursor = collection.find({'score': {'$gt': threshold}})
```

which returns a cursor of the query. Writing this to a list and doing the operations on the list is much slower than if I had the option to re-query this cursor with fx

```
query_cursor.find({'filename': 'abc'})
```

However, because I need to do multiple operations on it, it's not feasible to constantly do

```
query_cursor = collection.find({'score': {'$gt': threshold}, 'filename': 'abc'})
```

So is there a way to query onto the cursor?

Comment: _"However, because I need to do multiple operations on it,..."_: In such case, you can use an Aggregation Query, which allows more complex operations on the input collection data. But, you can do some operations on the cursor too; see [Cursor Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html).

Comment: Will this also work in python and Pymongo? I tried to use the .forEach function which does not seem to be implemented in Pymongo

Comment: According to https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html the only option seems to be a .where search, which could be useful but not really what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

A cursor does not store the documents. It is essentially a pointer into the result set on the server. The driver retrieves the documents one batch at a time and forwards each batch to the application before getting the next batch.

There is also no facility in either drivers or server to rewind the cursor (or to skip ahead). Documents must be retrieved sequentially.

Therefore, the only supported operation on a cursor is to read all documents in the result set sequentially, one time.

If you want to perform multiple passes over the data you need to store it in your application or issue multiple queries (or have a single query produce all of the data you need).

You may be able to find a library that would filter the results in the application process. For example, Mongoid does that with [embedded matching](https://p-mongo.github.io/rendered-docs/mongoid/tutorial/tutorials/mongoid-relations.html#querying-loaded-associations).